Do I have to enable bluetooth connection on ubuntu for blueetooth mouse?
I realised that the bluetooth connection was turned off on Ubuntu even though I am using a bluetooth mouse. Pointer doesn't move smoothly since few days so I'm searching for the possible reasons. I think the mouse makes the bluetooth communication through its usb dongle but I wonder if I should enable bluetooth connection on Ubuntu as well. Turning it on didn't help to solve the problem though.

Yes, you have to enable Bluetooth to use a Bluetooth mouse.
If the mouse comes with a usb dongle then it’s not Bluetooth (which explains why it works even when Bluetooth is off). Some mice have Bluetooth capability as well as the dongle, but it was connecting via the dongle (typically 2.4GHz) connector as it worked when BT was off.
It doesn’t solve your issue with the mouse of course - you might want to try it in a different computer to check it isn’t a hardware issue (and obviously clean the led).
